# parsing a comma in ruby for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, gsub

So I'm looping through a object for loop in my ruby on rails app

currently this is the code:

```
<%overlays.by_time.each do |overlay| %>
  {
    "content": "<a href=''><img src='<%= overlay.imageurl %>'></a>",
     start: <%=overlay.starttime %>,
     end: <%=overlay.starttime %> + <%= overlay.duration %>,
     style: {<%=raw theme.contact_us_overlay_style %>},
     click_url: '<%= overlay.linkurl %>'
  },
<%end>
```

the problem is the comma, which preventing my videojs player from running. I need the comma for next preceding overlay content, but i don't need it on the last one, which  is the problem that causing it. How do i remove it on the last  object iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several possibilities. A quick (but not very elegant) one is to check whether the item is the latest one.

You can use for example `each_with_index`:

```
<% overlays.by_time.each_with_index do |overlay, index| %>
  {
    "content": "<a href=''><img src='<%= overlay.imageurl %>'></a>",
     start: <%=overlay.starttime %>,
     end: <%=overlay.starttime %> + <%= overlay.duration %>,
     style: {<%=raw theme.contact_us_overlay_style %>},
     click_url: '<%= overlay.linkurl %>'
  }<%= "," unless index == (overlays.length - 1) %>
<% end %>
```

A better alternative, since you are essentially producing a string output, would be to generate (may be using an helper) the string output for each overlay as item into an array, then use `join(",")` to concatenate the array values into a single string.

This code should not be part of an ERB template, but may be a function or helper.

```
def json_for_overlays(overlays)
  overlays.by_time.map do |overlay, index|
    <<-JS
    {
      content: <a href=""><img src="#{overlay.imageurl}"></a>,
      start: #{overlay.starttime},
      end: #{overlay.starttime} + #{overlay.duration},
      style: {#{raw(theme.contact_us_overlay_style)}},
      click_url: '#{overlay.linkurl}'
    }
    JS
  end.join(",")
end
```

Comment: you sir, are a gentlemen and scholar. I tried doing a gsub in my attempt but yours is much more simpler. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can look it this another way. Put the comma *before* each item. Then you just need to suppress the comma for the *0th* index.

```
<% overlays.by_time.each_with_index do |overlay, index| %>
  <%= "," unless index == 0 %>
  {
    "content": "<a href=''><img src='<%= overlay.imageurl %>'></a>",
     start: <%=overlay.starttime %>,
     end: <%=overlay.starttime %> + <%= overlay.duration %>,
     style: {<%=raw theme.contact_us_overlay_style %>},
     click_url: '<%= overlay.linkurl %>'
  }
<% end %>
```